# Get the view on orientation switch or when leaving application

Tags: android, android-manifest, screen-orientation

I'm pretty new to this Android Programming. But I'm trying to make an application that receives content from a web-based server - this functionality works like a charm - finally.

But, for several days have I tried to find an answer to why my application want remember its view on orientation switching, when view is change to another activity or when leaving application.

I know there is something with the manifest file to do, and the bundle, but It seems like I havent implementet this functionality correctly.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.getpublished.onskelisten"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Onskelisten"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutOnskelisten" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HandleLogin" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabHome" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabWishes" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TabWishlists"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Register" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserNotLoggedInOptions" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the "main-class .Onskelisten", that also includes the tabs:

```
package com.getpublished.onskelisten;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Onskelisten extends TabActivity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ( checkForExtStorage( this ) ) {

            Session.loadConfig( getSharedPreferences(Session.PREFS_NAME, 0 ) );

            if ( Session.checkToken() == false ) {

                startLogin();

            } else {

                startLoggedInSession( );

            }

        } else {

            finish();

        }

        //Session.setNewToken( getSharedPreferences( Session.PREFS_NAME, 0 ) );

    }

    public void startLogin () {

        Session.setNewToken( getSharedPreferences(Session.PREFS_NAME, 0), "", 0);

        Intent intent = (Intent) new Intent( this, UserNotLoggedInOptions.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void startLoggedInSession () {

        setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);

        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass( this, TabHome.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator( "Home",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_home))
                          .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass( this, TabWishes.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("wishes").setIndicator( "Wishes",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_wishes))
                          .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass( this, TabWishlists.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("wishlists").setIndicator( "Lists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_wishlists))
                          .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag("home");

    }

    public static void addNotification ( int noteId, int contentHeaderId, int contentTextId, Context context, Object className) {

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.icon32;
        String tickerTextString = (String) context.getString(contentHeaderId);
        CharSequence tickerText = (CharSequence) tickerTextString;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        String contentString = (String) context.getString(contentTextId);
        CharSequence contentText = (CharSequence) contentString;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, (Class<?>) className );
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, tickerText, contentText, contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();

        if ( Session.checkToken() == true ) {

            startLoggedInSession( );

        }else {

            startLogin( );

        }

    }

    public static boolean checkForExtStorage ( Context context ) {

        if ( Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) == false ) {
            Session.showUsertip( "External storage is missing", context );
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.log_out_token:
            startLogin( );
            return true;
        case R.id.goto_about:
            Intent intent = (Intent) new Intent( getApplicationContext(),AboutOnskelisten.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.lowerpopupmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause () {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

    }

}
```

This is the "home-tab-class, .TabHome", that loads content from my server. (As i mentioned; it work, but when i leave the tab'ed activity, it looses its view.)

```
package com.getpublished.onskelisten;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TabHome extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        renderHomeScreen( );

    }

    private void renderHomeScreen ( ) {

        Session.loadConfig( getSharedPreferences(Session.PREFS_NAME, 0 ) );

        LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) new LinearLayout(this);
        mainView.setId(1);
        mainView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        ViewGroup hScrollView = null;

        try {
            hScrollView = getLastContentFromWWW();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TabHome/getLastContentFromWWW", "" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mainView.addView( hScrollView );
        setContentView(mainView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        renderHomeScreen( );

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    }

    @Override 
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private ViewGroup getLastContentFromWWW ( ) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Token", Session.TOKEN ));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GetImages", "Y") );
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Last", "10") );
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Size", "100x100") );

        HorizontalScrollView ScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView( this );
        ScrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ScrollView.setId(2);
        ScrollView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.panelbg);

        TableLayout scrollWrapper = (TableLayout) new TableLayout(this);
        scrollWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        scrollWrapper.setId(3);

        LinearLayout scrollChildHead = (LinearLayout) new LinearLayout(this);
        scrollChildHead.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        scrollChildHead.setId(4);

        TableRow scrollChildContent = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
        scrollChildContent.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        scrollChildContent.setId(5);

        TextView scrollHeader = new TextView(this);
        scrollHeader.setText(R.string.last_images_from_site);
        scrollHeader.setTextSize(20);
        scrollHeader.setId(6);

        scrollChildHead.addView(scrollHeader);

        scrollWrapper.addView(scrollChildHead);


        String response = null;

        // TODO: Fetch locally stored images?

        /**
         * QUERY:
         * http://onskelisten.getpublished.no/Mobile/MobileApps/
         * ?Platform=Android
         * &Version=V1.0
         * &Token=*static*
         * &LastContent=Y
         */

        if ( response == null ) {

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(postParameters);
                Log.i("Response/getWWW", response);
                JSONGetServerResults.validateResponse(response, this, getSharedPreferences(Session.PREFS_NAME, 0));
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost/JSONGetServerResults.validateResponse", "" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        JSONObject lastContentObj = null;
        JSONArray lastContentObjPics = null;

        try {

            lastContentObj = JSONGetServerResults.createNewObject( response );

        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("lastContentObj/lastContentObj1", "" + e.getMessage());
        }

        if ( lastContentObj.has( "LastImages") )
            lastContentObjPics = lastContentObj.getJSONArray( "LastImages" );

        for ( int i = 0; i < lastContentObjPics.length(); i++ ) {

            Bitmap bitmapFromURL = null;

            try {

                bitmapFromURL = CustomHttpClient.getImageBitmap(lastContentObjPics.getJSONObject(i).getString("EntPic"));

            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("CustomHttpClient.getImageBitmap", "" + e.getMessage());
            }

            if ( bitmapFromURL != null ) {

                ImageView newImage = (ImageView) new ImageView(this);
                newImage.setContentDescription(lastContentObjPics.getJSONObject(i).getString("EntName"));
                newImage.setMinimumHeight(100);
                newImage.setMinimumWidth(100);
                newImage.setMaxHeight(100);
                newImage.setMaxWidth(100);
                newImage.setClickable(true);
                newImage.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                newImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_100x100_w_border);
                newImage.setId( i + 100 );

                newImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromURL);

                final int newId = (int) new Integer( lastContentObjPics.getJSONObject(i).getString("EntId"));

                newImage.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://onskelisten.getpublished.no/Show/Entry/" + newId + "/"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }
                });

                scrollChildContent.addView(newImage);
            }

        }

        scrollWrapper.addView(scrollChildContent);
        ScrollView.addView(scrollWrapper);

        return ScrollView;


    }

}
```

And the "Session class" that saves information from the server, so the application can receive the content it needs.

```
package com.getpublished.onskelisten;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Session {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Onskelisten";
    public static String TOKEN;
    public static long TOKENLIFETIME;
    public static long TOKENCHECKEDNOW;
    public static boolean TOKENCHECK;

    public static Serializable LastImages;

    public static void setNewToken ( SharedPreferences settings, String token, long tokenLifetime ) {

        // SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString( "Token", token ).commit();
        editor.putLong( "TokenLifetime", tokenLifetime ).commit();

        loadConfig( settings );

        checkToken();

    }

    public static void loadConfig ( SharedPreferences settings ) {

        Session.TOKEN = settings.getString("Token", "");
        Session.TOKENLIFETIME = settings.getLong("TokenLifetime", 0);

        checkToken();

    }

    public static boolean checkToken () {

        Calendar timestampC = (Calendar) Calendar.getInstance();
        Session.TOKENCHECKEDNOW = (timestampC.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);

        if ( Session.TOKEN == "" || Session.TOKENCHECKEDNOW > Session.TOKENLIFETIME )
            Session.TOKENCHECK = false;
        else
            Session.TOKENCHECK = true;

        /*String tokenString = "Token: " + TOKEN;
        tokenString += "\nTokenLifetime " + TOKENLIFETIME;
        tokenString += "\nTokenChecked: " + TOKENCHECKEDNOW;
        tokenString += "\nTokenCheck: " + ( TOKENCHECK == false ? "FALSE" : "TRUE" );

        Toast.makeText( getContext(), tokenString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        return Session.TOKENCHECK;
    }

    public static void showUsertip ( CharSequence charSequence, Context context ) {

        Toast.makeText( context, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Edit: I removed some code, and it seems like the application now works perfectly on screen-orientation. Updated the codes. But there is still problems when leaving the app, unfortunally.

Comment: Why would you do this? As an user I don't want a forced orientation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to save your application state in a file/database or as a key value pair in the activity/application preferences and re-initialize your activity after reading those values. Android does not automatically save state when the activity is re-oriented or an activity finish()es.

Comment: Hmmm, i'm not sure what I need to save then, and how. Save the whole view that is created? Its strange that it can re-create the view in the other tabs. 

But in these activities I dont create the view in the class, like I do in TabHome-class(see renderHomeScreen();). They have own xml-files that I set with setContentView(R.layout.id);

Comment: You need to save all the data which is needed to create the view. For ListViews you might need to save the array which populates the view. Might have to keep a handler if you are using a bitmap. Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html. Also, go through the Android activity life cycle in the docs. Here is another article on this: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/1954